# Using a local database for java application

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I am currently undergoing a project which requires a database. So far uptil now I have been using a sql localhost database, I was wondering if there was an alternative to this.

Similar to micrsoft access database where I could read from the local database file instead?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are talking about an embedded database.

Take a look at:  http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use Hypersonic or Derby; the latter is part of the JDK now.  SQLite is another possibility.

Comment: +1 for SQLite. We're using SQLite for storing system configuration. It has long history, efficient, many unit tests and many language bindings.